# How to repeat "key" in ngRepeat one time only (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

The problem is leaving in the JSON Array response from the Backend/DB. I'm getting the response of the database in the correct json format:

```
[
  0: {
       "Grade": 100,
       "AB001": 1,
       "AB002": 0,
       "AB003": 9,
       "AB004": 5
     },
  1: {
       "Grade": 98,
       "AB001": 3,
       "AB002": 0,
       "AB003": 0,
       "AB004": 0
     }
...
] (10 objects as result)
```

Thus displayed in the Firebug console, when you click the Response of the GET Request. To retrieve the keys who are represented in double quotes I've used the ngRepeat directive in my view like following:

```
<thead>
  <tr ng-repeat="d in data">
      <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in d">
          {{key}}
      </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
...
```

Only the problem is, that the key gets repeated 10 times. But I want to repeat the keys one time that means for example the key `Grade` is only one time in a th-tag and so on..

How can I implement this? I've tried it with angular's `forEach()` but it wasn't a solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the exact same keys in each object in the array, you could achieve this with:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in data[0]">
        {{key}}
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

In your snippet you are doing a double loop, listing each key, for each element in the array.

Comment: This is a nice solution but when my pivot table gets a new column with `AB011` then it isn't in the old reports. Is it possible to check this in a function and implement it in the ngRepeat directive?

Comment: I guess it would be works with `track by function()`, isn't it?

Comment: If the objects in the array could have different keys, then to get a full list, you would probably be best to write a function in the response `success` callback that can quickly loop through the keys of each object and add them to a tracking array if they are not already in it. Then you would use ng-repeat on the values in this tracking array instead.

Comment: hmm ok I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the **unique** filter from AngularUI (source code available here: [AngularUI unique filter](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js)) and use it directly in the ng-options (or ng-repeat).

Try This:

```
<thead>
  <tr ng-repeat="d in data">
      <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in d | unique:'key'">
          {{key}}
      </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If it worked for you, you can mark it as an answer  :P

Answer (score 0):

this answer may be help you

```
<thead>
<tr ng-repeat="d in data">
   <th ng-if="$parent.$index == 0" ng-repeat="(key, value) in d">
       {{key}}
   </th>
</tr>
```