# AngularJS - ng-repeat of rows inside tables

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

### AngularJS - ng-repeat & $http.get

Edit: Tried using **unique**, also did not work:

```
<table class="table" ng-controller="fetchData">
    <tr ng-repeat="elements in rawData.value">
        <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in elements | unique:'key'">
            {{key}}
        </th>
        <td ng-repeat="element in elements">
            {{ element }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm filling tables with external information using ng-repeat, but I am struggling with filling the headers. I found an example to extract the keys:

```
<td ng-repeat="(key, element) in elements">
```

However, this does not help me as I should fill the th just one time, over the data, not beside it. I also tried adding an additional ng-repeat, to no avail.

Regaring $http.get and ODATA-sources - is there any way to populate the table with all available data at once? Or anywhere I can read which tokens are accepted (did not find any information when googling)? Right now I'm only geting a max of 11 elements - and I'm not allowed to add the token to the URL the way I am doing at the moment. Is there a better way to fetch the data? Any pointers would be appreciated, please let me know if additional information is needed. This is the code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ODataResources/1.0.25/odataresources.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
  </head>

<script>
    const BASE_URL = 'http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/';

    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

    var app = angular.module('getData', []);
    app.controller('fetchLinks', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get(BASE_URL)
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.rawLinks = response.data;
        });
    });
    app.controller('fetchData', function($scope, $http) {
        let dynamicContent = getParameterByName('q');
        console.log(BASE_URL+dynamicContent);
        $http.get(BASE_URL+dynamicContent)
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.rawData = response.data;
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
  <body ng-app="getData">
        <div class="container main-container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col menu">
                        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button>
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                            <ul>
                                <div ng-controller="fetchLinks">
                                    <li class="nav-item" ng-repeat="element in rawLinks.value">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="?q={{ element.url }}">{{ element.name }}</a>
                                    </li>
                                </div>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 content">
                        <table class="table" ng-controller="fetchData">
                            <tr ng-repeat="elements in rawData.value">
                                <td ng-repeat="element in elements">
                                    {{ element }}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: so your problem is only on table headers? (`<th>`)

Comment: There should be only one `ng-app` directive on a page. The `ng-app="links"` will be ignored.

Comment: @Sajjad Shahi: Yes, I would like to display the key values in <th>. I tried an extra ng-repeat with (key, element) over the existing in my code, but still wasn't able to get the keys, only the repeated data.

Comment: @georgeawg: Thanks, that shouldn't be there, I've edited that now. Didn't know there could be only one though, thanks for the info. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To repeat multiple rows, use the [Special Repeat Start and End Points](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points):

```
<table class="table" ng-controller="fetchData">
    <tr ng-repeat-start="elements in rawData.value">
        <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in elements>
            {{key}}
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end>
        <td ng-repeat="element in elements">
            {{ element }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This will repeat two rows; the first with keys and the second with values.

---

> Your code does almost what I wanted to achieve, so I added an `ng-if="$first"` to the `ng-repeat-start` line

If your goal is to create only one header row, it is more efficient to do it as:

```
<table class="table" ng-controller="fetchData">
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in rawData.value[0]">
            {{key}}
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="elements in rawData.value">
        <td ng-repeat="element in elements">
            {{ element }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This avoids all the overhead with evaluating multiple `ng-if` expressions. It also assumes that every object in the `rawData.value` array has the same keys.

Comment: Thanks, I was just looking at that function on another question ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32716999/how-to-repeat-key-in-ngrepeat-one-time-only-angularjs ) actually, but I did not get it working at first try. Your code does almost what I wanted to achieve, so I added an ng-if="$first" to the "ng-repeat-start"-line - it is perfect now! Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! :)